# Example using 'super' In Python2.7

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I am trying to extend my class initialization using super in python. In the below example I want `Class A` to initialize a parameter multiplied by 4 and I want this parameter to be available in class B via inheritance. I then want another initialization in B to take that same parameter and multiply it by 8 instead. This second initialization doesn't have to be available in A.

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,parameter):
        self.initialize_parameter=4*parameter

class B(A):
    def __init__(self,parameter): #note this parameter is intended to be the same parameter from Class A
        self.another_parameter=parameter*8
        super(B,self).__init__(parameter)
```

The documents I've been reading seem to indicate that the above is the correct syntax (I think) but the doc on this subject is rather confusing. The above code returns `TypeError: must be type, not classobj`.

This is my first time using inheritance, can anybody suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: FWIW, it's more usual practice to call the super `__init__` (if you need to call it at all) as the first command in the child `__init__`, rather than doing it at the end. That way it's easier for the child initializer to override or augment stuff that gets done by the  super initializer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax would be `class A(object)`, not `Class A()`.

Note that I've both lower-cased the keyword `class` (which leads me to believe that your code here was not copy-pasted - it is a bad idea to ask for help on code which you have not tried to run!), and also added the word `object` inside the parens to mark this as a new-type Python class. The latter is idiomatic, if not strictly necessary.

When I try to run your code exactly as you have written it, I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. When I lower-case the word `class`, I get no errors at all on Python 2.7.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `super` is not supported by old-style classes, i.e. those that do not ultimately inherit from `object`. That is the reason for the `TypeError` exception.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I tried to abstract my situation without actually testing the code and obviously made mistakes - a bad idea , point taken

Comment: Do you mean in my example I would have to add parameter to the class definition i.e. the first line would be `class A(parameter)`?

Comment: @user3059024: You literally need `class A(object):` as the first line of `A`'s definition.

Comment: Ah okay, `object` is a keyword. I understand now, thank you

Comment: @user3059024: Not a problem. But `object` isn't exactly a keyword: it's the base class object that other (new-style) classes inherit from. One important ability that deriving from the `object` class gives a class is the ability to use `super()`